# Win 10 shortcut hotkey list location

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, batch, windows-registry, shortcuts

I am looking for a file or `Reg Key`  that holds current shortcut hotkey combinations, i.e.:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

I have a few batch files with hotkeys assigned, but after each win update I need to reassign the combination.

So far I use another batch file that deletes and recreates shortcuts, but I'd like to reregister them instead of having to recteate them.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet to display *user-made keyboard shortcuts* is to use a third-party tool, such as Nirsoft's free [ShortcutsMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shman.html), with the *caveat* that this only shows those keyboard shortcuts made using the *Windows* mechanism, *not* those made using other tools, such as [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [Clavier+](https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/?lang=en). However, those applications show all shortcuts made in them, so that should not be an issue.

Also note that [Windows has it own plethora of shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec), which may change after updates.

Comment: While I would like nothing more onstall some third party softwarw and be done with it, it's out of the question. Company workstation.

Comment: Sorry about that -- the Nirsoft tool is portable, needing no installation, but if the company forbids even that, it's not worth losing one's job.

Comment: I realise that this comment comes very late but...
I've downloaded SHMan and tested the software. Unfortunately it does not show shortcuts with broken hotkey combination as pink (or 'corrupted') so it does not do what I need it to. I'll stay with my currenct solution of removing .lnk files via batch file and recreating them, with hotkeys assigned, via vbs script.